# Android native open flutter screen

Tags: flutter

**How can I open a flutter screen from Android-Native-Screen?**

I Was open an **Android-Native-Screen** from existing our **Flutter project**.

So, on **Android-Native-Screen**, we need open **Flutter-Screen**.

That means our work-flow: FLutter -> Native-Android-Activity -> Flutter Screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flutter provides FlutterActivity to display a Flutter experience within an Android app. Like any other Activity**

You can go through this Documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen

Step 1: Add FlutterActivity to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
  android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
  />
```

Step 2: Launch FlutterActivity

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(
      FlutterActivity.createDefaultIntent(currentActivity)
    );
  }
});
```

The following example demonstrates how to launch a FlutterActivity that initially renders a custom route in Flutter.

```
   myButton.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(
          FlutterActivity
            .withNewEngine()
            .initialRoute("/my_route")
            .build(currentActivity)
          );
      }
    });
```

Comment: Yah, it's work for me.
The new issue when I back from my_route, it not back directly to Android-Native-Screen, It back to the home route (slash route).

Comment: How to pass argument  while moving to flutter screen from native?